# How to implement HandlerFunc without using DefaultServeMux

Tags: go

If I were to use the DefaultServeMux (which I designate by passing `nil` as the second argument to ListenAndServe), then I have access to `http.HandleFunc`, which you see used below in this example from the Go wiki:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

In my current code, I am not able to use the DefaultServeMux i.e. I'm passing a custom handler to ListenAndServe

```
    h := &mypackage.Handler{
        Database: mydb
    }
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", h)
```

so I don't get the `http.HandleFunc` built in. However, I have to adapt some authorization code to my code base that requires something like `http.HandleFunc`. For example, if I had been using DefaultServeMux,  when I hit the `"/protected"` route, I would want to go to the `Protected` handler, but only after passing through the `h.AuthorizationHandlerFunc` like this

```
   h.AuthorizationHandlerFunc(Protected)
```

However, since I'm not using DefaultServeMux, it's not working i.e. I'm not able to pass the `Protected` function (and have it called) to the `AuthorizationHandlerFunc`. This is the implementation of the AuthorizationHandlerFunc below. You can see below that `Protected` never gets called.

Question: how do I implement `HandlerFunc` in this situation (without using DefaultServeMux)?

```
func (h *Handler) AuthorizationHandlerFunc(next http.HandlerFunc) http.Handler{
     return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
         h.AuthorizationMiddleWare(w, r, next)
   })
}

func (h *Handler) AuthorizationMiddleWare(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc){
     //other stuff happens
     log.Println("this is never getting called")
     next(w,r)
}
func (h *Handler)Protected(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

      log.Println("this is never getting called")
}
```

**Update**
ServeHTTP is implemented on mypackage.Handler. Why is the Protected function not getting called, or, for that matter, the relevant code in the AuthorizationMiddleWare?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. I _think_ all youn eed is to implement ServeHTTP  on your mypackage.Handler and do the routing yourself i.e. look at the path and call the entry of your chained handler functions if /protected is hit.

Comment: @Volker that code above is implemented, and when /protected is hit, the function Protected is not getting called. ServeHTTP is implemented on `mypackage.Handler`

Comment: I'd suggest moving away from `http.HandlerFunc` (which is a concrete type) and accepting `http.Handler` - which is where having a ServeHTTP method comes in.

Comment: To respond to your update: where is Protected getting invoked? If you have a `ServeHTTP` method, you need to call it from within there, otherwise it won't be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-implement your authorization middleware as a `http.Handler` :

```
type auth struct {
   DB *sql.DB
   UnauthorizedHandler http.Handler
}

func NewAuth(db *sql.DB, unauthorized http.Handler) *auth {
    return auth{db, unauthorized}
}

func (a *auth) Protected(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Check whether the request is valid
        // If it's invalid, call your error func and make sure to *return* early!
        if !valid {
            a.UnauthorizedHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        // Call the next handler on success
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return
    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello!\n")
}

func main() {
    auth := NewAuth(db, errorHandler)
    r := http.NewServeMux()
    // We have a http.Handler implementation that wraps a http.HandlerFunc
    // ... so we call r.Handle on our ServeMux and type-cast the wrapped func
    r.Handle("/protected", auth.Protected(http.HandlerFunc(someHandler)))
    // Just a simple http.HandlerFunc here
    r.HandleFunc("/public", someOtherHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

Take a look at the [httpauth lib I wrote](https://github.com/goji/httpauth/blob/master/basic_auth.go) for a different example with a `ServeHTTP` method. Both the above and explicitly creating a `ServeHTTP` method on your type are valid approaches.

Comment: Thank you. would this solution only work with using http.NewServeMux()? For example, if you just create a custom Handler with a ServeHTTP method and then inside serve http switched on r.URL.Path? Do I need to use http.NewServeMux if not using the DefaultServeMux?

Comment: You can use the default ServeMux if you want - it works either way. I find it good practice to create your own ServeMux to avoid any implicit behaviour (i.e. if you turn profiling on, the default mux exposes your internal goroutine state)

Comment: I got my code to work by calling the AuthorizationMiddleware directly like this `h.(w,r, Protected)`, bypassing my `AuthorizationHandlerFunc` entirely. However your code showed me how to get it to work as well and it's a better solution so I accepted your answer.