# How to compose a new ServeMux into a larger struct?

Tags: go

In previous golang applications I've made that use the DefaultServeMux, if I had a route like this `"/users/"` route that was handled by `func user(name string)`, for example, and I sent a request to `/users/jim`, the request would still be handled by the `"/users/"` route. In the current application I'm making, I'm not using `DefaultServeMux` but merely passing a handler that implements ServeHTTP and then switching on the request url. However, now, if I send a request to a route that doesn't exactly match, the handler function doesn't get called. For example, if I send a post request to `"/api/jim"`, I get a 404 error even though `"/api"` is handled.

I want to keep my application the way it is (with a reference to the DB in the handler) but also be able to handle routes that don't match exactly.

Question: Assuming I could create a new ServeMux to handle routes that don't exactly match, but how can I compose that with my type Handler Struct that has the reference to the database connection?

```
type Handler struct{
  DB *DB
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")


    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    defer db.Close()

    h := &Handler{
      DB: db,
    }

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8888", h))
}

func (h *Handler)ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    switch r.URL.Path{
        case "/":
        h.serveRoot(w, r)
        case "/api/":
        h.apiRouter(w, r)
    }
}

func (h *Handler)serveRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        h.DB.DoSomethingWithDB()
}

func (h *Handler)apiRouter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

       switch r.URL.Path{

           case "/":
               h.serveRoot(w, r)
           case "/api/":
               h.apiRouter(w, r)

       }
}
```

**Update**
For reasons that aren't relevant to the question, I can't use DefaultServeMux

Comment: I don't see what functionality you want that isn't provided by [`http.ServeMux`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux). `ServeMux` is just a type of handler that can dispatch to other handlers based on the request. There's also a plethora of http router packages for Go with various features if `ServeMux` doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: For reasons that aren't relevant to the question,  I can't use DefaultServeMux (I'll update the OP to mention that), so I have to either create a new ServeMux or do what I did in the OP. Either way, I would like to figure out how to keep a reference to the database with the handler

Comment: So don't use DefaultServeMux, and create a new instance of ServeMux.

Comment: @JimB I guess my question isn't clear. that's what I want to do, but I don't know how to integrate it with the handler that has the reference to the database. that's the whole point of the question. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: DefaultServeMux *is* a ServeMux, and you use it the exact same way. The only difference is you have to choose to use your new ServeMux, by giving it to ListenAndServe or your instance of http.Server. Try [looking at the source](http://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?#L1938) for the http convenience methods methods if you're not sure what they do.

Comment: You seem to be asking the exact same question you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330744/how-to-implement-handlerfunc-without-using-defaultservemux

Comment: same topic area, but not the same question.

Comment: It's not the same question (which is why I didn't mark it as an exact duplicate), but the answer is nearly the same. It shows how to create and use a ServeMux to route requests to different handlers. Otherwise you need to tell us what ServeMux doesn't provide that you're missing.

Comment: ok, looking at the answer that was provided. Assume that code was in main.go of `package main` (and main.go was the only file in that package) but your project was composed of several packages (i.e. not just that package main), and the `type auth struct` was part of one of the other packages. How to compose the reference to the NewServeMux into the auth struct so you can handle routing in the other packages of your project I.e I don't want every route of my project defined in the main function of main.go That's what I'm asking in this op but with more context. Thanks for helping if it's clear

Comment: i.e. the goal is to avoid handling routing in `func main` of package main, but instead to have a reference to the mux in a struct in one of the other packages in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom handler struct, a ServeMux, a HandlerFunc, and 3rd party routers are *all* of type `http.Handler`. You can compose and layer them as needed.

Since a ServeMux is a Handler, you can assign it to a path just like any other handler, and register separate paths for various handlers. Here's an example of using multiple `http.ServeMux` (which could be defined in separate packages if you choose). This has 3 separate handlers (defined via a `HandlerFunc`), routed over 2 `ServeMux`.

Here we have a ServeMux create in a package "router"

```
var Sub = http.NewServeMux()

func subHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("handled / in /sub")
    w.Write([]byte("/sub/\n"))
}    

func init() {
    Sub.HandleFunc("/", subHandler)
}
```

Now we can import the ServeMux from "router", and use it in our top level Handler, along with some others:

```
import "router"

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("handled /")
    w.Write([]byte("/\n"))
}

func topHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("handled /top")
    w.Write([]byte("/top/\n"))
}
func main() {

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/top/", topHandler)

    // now insert the Sub routes under "/top/sub/"
    mux.Handle("/top/sub/", http.StripPrefix("/top", router.Sub))

    server := &http.Server{Addr: ":9999", Handler: mux}
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

How you choose to register these is up to you, either via importing and routing them like this in the `main` package, or via some other registration pattern (like e.g the `database/sql` drivers).

There's also no shortage of 3rd party routing packages to make this easier, higher performance, or provide more advanced methods of pattern matching.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort but the point of the question was how to use the NewServeMux outside of the main function of `package main`  (say, for example, by making it part of a type Handler struct from one of th eother packages) and those are the only examples you provided. I'll give you an upvote but I can't accept the answer because it doesn't respond to the question.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: I'm really failing to see what you're missing. This shows exactly that; there's no reason you can't define the `sub` `ServeMux` in a separate package and choose how to rout it in main, or as I mentioned, you could provide a registration pattern for `sub`'s package to register routes itself ( for example, `net/http/pprof` self-registers routes in the `DefaultServeMux`)

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: I changed the example to do the exact same thing, except import the ServeMux from another package.